# how to pick a particular version from requirement.txt file

Tags: python

I have requirements.txt file, where I give the custom-package name with version as below,

```
custom-package >= 1.0.1
```

Now in my repo, i have versions like below

```
custom-package-1.0.1.tar.gz
custom-package-1.0.4.tar.gz
custom-package-5.0.0.tar.gz
```

now if I run pip install requirements.txt , then it picks up 5.0.0. which is understandable. 
But how can I make sure, it should only pick up the version starts with 1 not with 5.

Comment: `custom-package == 1.0.1`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want any version that starts with 1, just specify that the version shouldn't exceed 2.0.0:

```
custom-package >= 1.0.1, < 2.0.0
```

or if you want an exact version:

```
custom-package == 1.0.1
```

Comment: let me try with `~=` , and your suggestion with ` > and < ` options

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose any version starting with '1', just do:

```
custom-package == 1.*
```

Comment: But the picked version can be for example `1.0.0` which is lower than `1.0.1`

Comment: requirement says it should only pick up the version starts with 1 not with 5. I think this might suffice

Comment: @AminGuermazi - again, the question is pretty specific about it: "it should only pick up the version starts with 1". As "1.*" starts with one, I believe it answers the question.

Comment: Exactly, He downvoted my answer too! based on how he understood the question

Answer (score -1):

```
custom-package==1.*
```

This should do

Comment: But the picked version can be for example `1.0.0` which is lower than `1.0.1`

Comment: requirement says it should only pick up the version starts with 1 not with 5. I think this might suffice

Comment: But not in all cases, specifying the starting version number is always more precise

Comment: 1.0.0 is okay , please read 'pick up the version starts with 1'. i dont undersatnd how 1.0.0 doesn't start with 1?